Rewriting complex matrix as a tensor product
Consider the following matrix:
$$\tilde A=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}^* & 0 & A_{12}^* & 0 & \dots & A_{1n}^* & 0 \\ 0 & A_{11} & 0 & A_{12} & \dots & 0 & A_{1n} \\ A_{21}^* & 0 & A_{22}^* & 0 & \dots & A_{2n}^* & 0 \\ 0 & A_{21} & 0 & A_{22} & \dots & 0 & A_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ A_{n1} ^* 
 & 0 & A_{n2}^* & 0 & \dots & A_{nn}^* & 0 \\ 0  
 & A_{n1} & 0 & A_{n2} & \dots & 0 & A_{nn}\end{pmatrix} $$
If all entries are real, then we can conveniently write $\tilde A=A\otimes I$, where $I$ is the appropriately sized identity matrix. Is it possible to express $\tilde A$ in a simpler, tensor form even in the more general complex case?

$({\rm Re},A)\otimes I+({\rm Im},A)\otimes{\rm diag}(1,-1)$? Can also write ${\rm Re},A=\frac{1}{2}(A+\overline{A})$ and ${\rm Im},A=\frac{1}{2i}(A-\overline{A})$.

@coiso Are you forgetting a factor of $i$ somewhere, or is it all accounted for?

Oh yeah, should put $i$ in front of ${\rm Im},A$. Also since you put conjugates before nonconjugates, I guess I should say ${\rm diag}(-1,1)$ instead of ${\rm diag}(1,-1)$.
